# Extract nested entities and values from JSON

Tags: json, scala, jira, lift, case-class

I am trying to extract Issues from Jira and put them into List[Issue].
I figured out how to download and parse JSON:

```
val json = JsonParser.parse(content)
```

I can also extract some numbers in the root of JSON:

```
val total = (json \ "total").extract[Int]
val maxResults = (json \ "maxResults").extract[Int]
println("Received " + total + " from " + maxResults + " issues")
```

But when I am trying to extract list of all the issues

```
val issues = (json \ "issues")
println(issues)
issues.extract[List[Issue]]
```

I am receiving a error:
Exception in thread "main" net.liftweb.json.MappingException: No usable value for id
Do not know how to convert JString(13604) into int
I don't understand why can't it convert 13604 to Int.
Here is my case class:

```
case class Issue(id: Int,
    key: String,
    summary: String,
    issueTypeName: String,
    resolutionName: Option[String],
    resolutionDate: Option[DateTime],
    timeSpent: Option[Int],
    creatorName: String,
    reporterName: String,
    updated: DateTime,
    created: DateTime,
    priorityName: String,
    description: String,
    dueDate: Option[DateTime],
    statusName: String,
    assigneeName: String,
    projectId: Int,
    projectKey: String,
    projectName: String,
    timeEstimate: Option[Int],
    ownerName: String,
    timeOriginalEstimate: Option[Int]
                    )
```

1. Can someone help me with this Int problem?
2. Moreover, JSON has nested elements for some properties  like project has nested id, key and name. Before I extracted issues with `json \ "issues"`  I saw another error - I believe it is because JSON extractor don't know he need to go to the nested elements.
   How can I let him know about it? 
   I thought I could do something like this:

   for(issue <- issues) {
     val id = (issue \ "id").extract[Int]
     println(id)
   }

And use `issue \ "project" \ "id"` for nested items, and then create new Case Class object and add it to List var (mutable but I have no idea how to do it in other way). But I receive compile time error:

```
 Error:(53, 16) value foreach is not a member of net.liftweb.json.JsonAST.JValue
        for(issue <- issues) {
                     ^
```

I am new to Scala and overall Java infrastructure and frameworks, so I would appreciate for samples of code.

---

PS. When I changed id to String in my case class I now receive another error:

```
Exception in thread "main" net.liftweb.json.MappingException: No usable value for summary Did not find value which can be converted into java.lang.String
```

This is because "summary" is nested into the "fields". So, my second question is still actual:
2. How can I work with nested values?

and new related question:
3. If I want to use Int for id - how can I convert it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found solution myself:

```
val issues = (json \\ "issues").children
 for (issue <- issues) {
        val item = new Issue (
                    (issue \ "id").extract[String].toInt,
                    (issue \ "fields" \ "summary").extract[String],
                    (issue \ "fields" \ "issuetype" \ "name").extract[String],
                    (issue \ "fields" \ "resolutiondate").extractOrNone[String] match {
                        case None => None
                        case Some (null) => None
                        case Some (dt) => Some (dateTimeFormatter.withZoneUTC ().parseDateTime (dt))
                    },
        etc...) 
}
```

In this case I continue using single case class (the structure I define for my own needs) and parse nested json properties into it, doing types transformations on the fly where needed.

Answer (score 4):

That's because the id field in the json comes in as a string ("id": "10230" https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+Query+issues ), which liftjson automatically converts to a JString. In your case class you need to make the id field a String.

2) use case classes to deal with nested json. If you have a json that looks like this

```
{
  "id": "10230",
  "fields": {
    "summary": "testing"
  }
}
```

you will need two case classes

```
case class Issues(
   id: String,
   fields: Summary
)

case class Summary(
   summary: String
)
```

3) I don't think you can convert to Int in the extract method because the JSON structure defines it as a String. The conversion will have to happen after you extract the value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - it is helpful. However now I receive an error:   Exception in thread "main" net.liftweb.json.MappingException: No usable value for summary
Did not find value which can be converted into java.lang.String   - this is because "summary" is nested into the "fields".  1. How can I work with nested values?   2. If I need to use Int for id - how can I convert it?

Comment: @KonstantinTrunin DId you get a solution for the problem you mentioned in the comment above ? TIA